# Filtering result set based on a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Given this result set, how do I pull out only those entries that have numbers greater than `2` but no entry for `1` in the `mdline` column, based on a unique `mmatter` column?

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8c17e/2

Query:

```
SELECT top 1000
       [mdindex]
      ,[mmatter]
      ,[mdline]
      ,[mddesc]
FROM [desc]
WHERE [mmatter] IN (
    SELECT [mmatter]
    FROM [desc]
    GROUP BY [mmatter]
     HAVING COUNT(distinct [mdline]) > 1
)
order by mmatter
```

Results:

```
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| mdindex | mmatter       | mdline | mddesc                  |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 142     | X30539.000021 | 1      | Avocet, pied            |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 143     | X30539.000021 | 2      | Margay                  |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 111     | X30820.004199 | 1      | African buffalo         |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 112     | X30820.004199 | 2      | Siskin, pine            |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 113     | X30820.004199 | 3      | African jacana          |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 114     | X30820.0042   | 2      | Caracara, yellow-headed |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 115     | X30820.0042   | 3      | Whip-tailed wallaby     |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 116     | X30820.0042   | 4      | Greater rhea            |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 120     | X30820.004202 | 1      | Nuthatch, red-breasted  |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 121     | X30820.004202 | 2      | Arctic tern             |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 122     | X30820.004202 | 3      | Tyrant flycatcher       |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 123     | X30820.004203 | 1      | Plover, three-banded    |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 124     | X30820.004203 | 2      | Tortoise, radiated      |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 129     | X30820.004204 | 2      | Laughing dove           |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 130     | X30820.004204 | 3      | Iguana, marine          |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+
```

This is the data I want to return, from the above result set:

```
+-----+---------------+---+-------------------------+
| 114 | X30820.0042   | 2 | Caracara, yellow-headed |
+-----+---------------+---+-------------------------+
| 115 | X30820.0042   | 3 | Whip-tailed wallaby     |
+-----+---------------+---+-------------------------+
| 116 | X30820.0042   | 4 | Greater rhea            |
+-----+---------------+---+-------------------------+
| 129 | X30820.004204 | 2 | Laughing dove           |
+-----+---------------+---+-------------------------+
| 130 | X30820.004204 | 3 | Iguana, marine          |
+-----+---------------+---+-------------------------+
```

Note that rows in this result set have no `mdline` value which is less than 2.

I tried this but get a syntax error, possibly due to nesting too many queries?

```
SELECT * FROM  
    ( SELECT top 1000
      [mdindex]
          ,[mmatter]
          ,[mdline]
          ,[mddesc]
    FROM [desc]
    WHERE [mmatter] IN (
        SELECT [mmatter]
        FROM [desc]
        GROUP BY [mmatter]
         HAVING COUNT(distinct [mdline]) > 1
        )
        order by mmatter
    )
WHERE mdline not like '1'
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) Also, your question is unclear.

Comment: Updated post to include a SQL Fiddle link. I'm not sure how you think it's unclear.

Comment: That's better. downvote retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired results by adding a `not exists` to your where clause:

```
SELECT [mdindex]
    ,[mmatter]
    ,[mdline]
    ,[mddesc]
FROM [table1] t0
WHERE [mmatter] IN (
    SELECT [mmatter]
    FROM [table1]
    GROUP BY [mmatter]
    HAVING COUNT(distinct [mdline]) > 1
)
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM [table1] t1
    WHERE t0.mmatter = t1.mmatter
    AND t0.mdline = 1
)
ORDER BY mmatter
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exists` & `not exists` :

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table1 t2
                  where t2.mmatter = t1.mmatter and t2.mdline = 1 
                  ) and
       exists (select 1 
               from table1 t2
               where t2.mmatter = t1.mmatter and t2.mdline <> t1.mdline
               );
```